# I tried to apply function "cliff" from installed package named "lace", I got the following error "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x

I read about the error and try to cast map into list, but the error still appeared, I will show you the main file that contain the error.

def power(L, C, Erange):

```
assert len(L) == len(C), "The L and C must be corresponded to each other"
E = copy.deepcopy(Erange)
E[0] -= 1
power_table = dict()
for c in set(C):  # for each type of class
    first = [index for index, eachc in enumerate(C) if eachc == c]
    rest = [index for index, eachc in enumerate(C) if eachc != c]
    p_first = len(first) / len(L)
    p_rest = len(rest) / len(L)


    powerc = []
    for u, v in zip(E[0:-1], E[1:]):  # checking the range (u,v]
        like_first = sum([1 for i in first if u < L[i] <= v]) / len(first) * p_first
        like_rest = sum([1 for i in rest if u < L[i] <= v]) / len(rest) * p_rest
        try:
            powerc.append((like_first ** 2 / (like_first + like_rest)))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
    powerc.append(0)


power_table[c] = powerc

 power = []
for l, c in zip(L, C):
    for e_cursor in range(len(E)):
        if E[e_cursor] >= l: break
    power.append(round(power_table[c][e_cursor - 1], 2))
return power
```

def cliff_core(data, percentage, obj_as_binary, handled_obj=False):

```
if len(data) < 50:
   logging.debug("no enough data to cliff. return the whole dataset")
   return range(len(data))


classes = map(toolkit.str2num, zip(*data)[-1])

if not handled_obj:
   if obj_as_binary:
      classes = [1 if i > 0 else 0 for i in classes]
   else:
      classes = toolkit.apply_bin_range(classes)


data_power = list() 


for col in zip(*data):
    col = map(toolkit.str2num, col)
    E = toolkit.binrange(col)
    data_power.append(power(col, classes, E))
    
 data_power = map(list, zip(*data_power))  # transposing the data power
 row_sum = [sum(row) for row in data_power]


 index = range(len(data))
 zips = zip(data, classes, row_sum, index)


 output = list()
 for cls in set(classes):
     matched = filter(lambda z: z[1] == cls, zips)
     random.shuffle(matched)
     matched = sorted(matched, key=lambda z: z[2], reverse=True)


     if len(matched) < 5:
        output.extend([m[3] for m in matched])  # all saved
        continue


     for i in range(int(len(matched) * percentage)):
        output.append(matched[i][3])
  return sorted(output)
```

def cliff(attribute_names,data_matrix,independent_attrs,objective_attr,objective_as_binary=False,
cliff_percentage=0.4):

```
ori_attrs, alldata = attribute_names, data_matrix  # load the database
alldata_t = map(list, zip(*alldata))
valued_data_t = list()
for attr, col in zip(ori_attrs, alldata_t):
if attr in independent_attrs:
valued_data_t.append(col)
valued_data_t.append(alldata_t[attribute_names.index(objective_attr)])  
alldata = map(list, zip(*valued_data_t))
alldata = map(lambda row: map(toolkit.str2num, row), alldata)  # numbering the 2d table
after_cliff = cliff_core(alldata, cliff_percentage, objective_as_binary)
res = [data_matrix[i] for i in after_cliff]
return res
```

Comment: Can anyone help

Comment: can any one help me to solve this error